# Twitter Bootsrap Modal :prevent asynchronous content load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to load the content of my Modals asynchronous with hinclude.js. So I render a remote page within my modal, but I dont want to request it just in the second when the modal is loaded (like the default modal). Since I want to make sure that the link is working alsow ithout javascript I want to use the real link to the remote page:

```
<a href="/web/app_dev.php/profile/suche" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-searchUser">
<i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>Leute finden</a>
```

The issue is that the content is already within the modal, but due to the `href="/web/app_dev.php/profile/suche"`
the content is again loaded.

How do I prevent Twitter from loading the content asynchronously on the click?

I've already tried:

```
$('[data-target="#modal-searchUser"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#strego_user_search_search').focus();
    });
```

Comment: How do you know that Bootstrap loads the content again? It already prevents default in https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-modal.js#L238

Comment: because there is 1. A small blink and the page returns different content on the hinclude load and the modal load... (this is also a big questionmark, but not topic of my issue here)